# Remote Database control How?

Tags: vb6

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Visual Basic 6.0 Remote database How?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8362795/visual-basic-6-0-remote-database-how)

I need VB6 code to connect a *.mdb file to one PC to another over the internet. When I update/save my database it must update via internet to other-side PC.

I wrote a VB6 simple database program that can save Roll_Num, Name, Address of student. It works on my PC, but how do I update/save/copy my *.mdb file to the other-side of the HOME PC by connecting it. How do I use my home PC to update it?

Comment: There are many more ways to do what you want that makes more sense.  For example, get a free website from Brinkster which comes with a database that you can use from anywhere.

Comment: @CatCall: Same person, same question... yeah, you're right :)

Answer (score 0):

You can generate XML and send XML over port 80 to an http listener that retrieves the file.  If you use asp you can use asp to save the file or parse the xml and then insert data into your mdb.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little un-clear but I understand it as that you will be making changes to an mdb file and you want to mirror these changes to another copy stored on a remote machine.

If this is the case then it may be worth while looking at writing an ftp script with overwrite properties set to True, so that you can simply transfer your copy and overwrite the existing copy on the remote machine.